# Platforms are not generating spaced out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a script spawning platforms every now and then but after a bit they group up and make it very laggy

moving script for the blocks:

```
       using System.Collections;
       using UnityEngine;

     public class SetMove : MonoBehaviour
     {
    int j;
    int y;

    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        y = Random.Range(15, 20);

        Rigidbody2D playerRG = GameObject.Find("player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        while (transform.position.x > -15)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.1f);

            transform.Translate(Vector3.left / 5);

            j++;

            if (j == y)
            {
                GameObject.Find("controller").GetComponent<set_make>().StartCoroutine("Start");

                y = Random.Range(15, 20);
            }

            if (playerRG.gravityScale == 0 && transform.position.x <= 0)
            {
                playerRG.gravityScale = 1;
                GameObject player = playerRG.gameObject;
                player.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0,          transform.localScale.y / 2);
            }
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        GameObject.Find("player").GetComponent<player>().canJump = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        GameObject.Find("player").GetComponent<player>().canJump = false;
    }
```

and the spawn script for the blocks is this:

```
          using System.Collections.Generic;
          using UnityEngine;
 
    public class set_make : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public GameObject short_block;
    public GameObject long_block;
    public GameObject med_block;
    int num;
    int pastnum;

    public void Start()
    {
        float level = -3.5f; 
        num = Random.Range(1, 4);
        switch (num)
        {
            case 1:
                Instantiate(short_block, new Vector3(13, level + 0.5f), Quaternion.identity);
                pastnum = num;
                break;
            case 2:
                Instantiate(med_block, new Vector3(13, level + 1f), Quaternion.identity);
                pastnum = num;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (pastnum != 1)
                {
                    Instantiate(long_block, new Vector3(13, level + 1.5f), Quaternion.identity);
                    pastnum = num;
                }
                else
                {
                    Start();
                }
                break;
        }
```

I tried changing the time between spawns but that did nothing and tried asking chat gpt but that failed. please help i am very stuck